# Translate ascii codes to AT set 2 keyboard scancodes

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I want to send a couple of characters with the `virtualbox controlvm keyboardputscancode` subcommand. The scancodes expected by virtualbox are the **IBM PC AT set 2 keyboard scancodes**, which in my case do not (always) correspond to the scancodes shown by e.g. `showkey -s`.

Idealy i want something which i could wrap into a bash script, so i could send arbitrary strings to the virtual machine like:

```
virtualbox controlvm <vm> keyboardputscancode $(asc2sc "My String here")
```

where `asc2sc` would be my bash-script!

Is there a scancode map for "IBM AT Set 2" keyboards, which i could use, without generating it myself? Regretfully Oracle is very vague about the specifics.

Comment: See also [Get keyboard scancode of char](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395500/get-keyboard-scancode-of-char)

Comment: Regretfully the mentioned post wasn't helpful. It's even borderline misleading!

Comment: It's the same question but unfortunately it currently only has a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to support a single keyboard layout in the VM, then it would be simplest to hard-code the conversion in your script.

```
typeset -A scancodes
scancodes['1']='02 82'  # press 1, release 1
scancodes['!']='2a 02 82 aa'  # press left Shift, press 1, release 1, release left shift
…
# emit_scancodes VM STRING
emit_scancodes () {
  typeset a=; typeset c string="$2"
  while [ -n "$string" ]; do
    c=${scancodes[${string:0:1}]
    if [ -z "$c" ]; then
      echo >&2 "Unsupported character: ${string:0:1}"
      return 1
    fi
    a+=("$c")
    string=${string:1}
  done
  for c in "${a[@]}"; do
    virtualbox controlvm "$1" keyboardputscancode
    # For long strings, you may need an additional short sleep here
  done
}
```

If you need to support a variety of keyboard layouts, then you can leverage Linux's console keymaps from the [Linux Console Tools data](http://lct.sourceforge.net/data.html). These files contain lines like

```
keycode 16 = q
keycode   2 = one              exclam
```

However, parsing the files to build conversion tables would be a nontrivial amount of work, and I'm not aware of it having been done.

Comment: Down-voting without comment should be banned, especially for helpful posts! Your post is helpful, but not to the point, where my problem is solved. I noticed, that it's not completely clear which AT set 2 scancodes Oracle is talking about. And it seems `showkey -s` does in some circumstances show the wrong scancodes. So my primary problem is a **reliable** mapping from chars to scancode, which your practical example regrettably couldn't  provide either. Btw., where do you exhaust `$2 to` to break the while loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, if you're aware, but Oracle specifically points out to use IBM AT set 2 **SCANCODES**, which are a complete different beast to linux (console) keycodes. There's a mapping between scancodes to keycodes, but it seems a reverse mapping from keycodes to scancodes do not return the *original raw **scancodes** *.

Comment: On the other hand you did correctly emphasize the use of the break codes, which Oracle conveniently seems to forget to mention, which took me a while to realize.

Comment: @DonQuestion Aren't Linux's keycodes equal to AT scancodes for all the keys that matter here, i.e. alphabetic keys and Shift? I fixed a bug in the script that had `$2` instead of `$string`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, im still trying to figure out what/why the codes change at all.